# Counting occurences of invisible ascii characters inside a character array?

Tags: java, arrays, if-statement, count, ascii

Here's what I tried to do, I tried splitting my string args into a much smaller type- char array hoping I could capture that 'empty space' between the words.

Just 0, what did I do wrong? I made sure I included all the invisible characters based on the ascii table.. D:

String args is an argument passed btw.

```
public static void showInvisibleCharacters(String[] args) {
```

`String words = "";
    int invisibleOccurenceCount = 0;
    char[] seperatedWords = words.toCharArray();

    for (int counter = 0; counter < words.toCharArray().length - 1; counter++) {
        if (seperatedWords[counter] == (char) 9) {
            invisibleOccurenceCount++;
        } else if (seperatedWords[counter] == (char) 10) {
            invisibleOccurenceCount++;
        } else if (seperatedWords[counter] == (char) 13) {
            invisibleOccurenceCount++;
        } else if (seperatedWords[counter] == (char) 28) {
            invisibleOccurenceCount++;
        } else if (seperatedWords[counter] == (char) 29) {
            invisibleOccurenceCount++;
        } else if (seperatedWords[counter] == (char) 30) {
            invisibleOccurenceCount++;
        } else if (seperatedWords[counter] == (char) 31) {
            invisibleOccurenceCount++;
        } else if (seperatedWords[counter] == (char) 32) {
            invisibleOccurenceCount++;
        } else if (seperatedWords[counter] == (char) 160) {
            invisibleOccurenceCount++;
        }
    }
    System.out.println("Number of invisible occurences: "
            + invisibleOccurenceCount);

}




}<code>`

Comment: share your error trace

Comment: length of char array is 0. for loop is not executed.

Comment: Why do you think that there are "invisible characters" in your string. Most strings do not contain these "invisible characters". You'd have to put them in there in purpose if you want to see them. Except code 32 is a normal space, so it's certainly not invisible. And 160 is a non-breaking space, also very visible. And 10 and 13 are newline and carriage return respectively, so you can see them as line breaks.

Answer (score 0):

You are just not referring to some `String` with actual value, but you are doing `String words = "";` means a blank `String` , so how can you expect to print *Invisible Characters*. The `for()` loop is just not executing once. Try referring some non blank `String`value in `words`, then check.

Answer (score -2):

String words = "";
Isn't this a problem? Don't you want to assign a string to it? When I tested it after assigning a proper string with spaces, it did work.